# Using Export Application Wizard eclipse android tool does not include the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've got a fairly simple Android application that I've been developing in Eclipse. Runs just fine on a test device if I install to the device through Eclipse Run/Debug.

Now that I'm ready to publish the app in the Android market I attempted to use the Android Tools->"Export Signed Application Package..." wizard. This wizard appeared to complete successfully. No errors or warnings in the Console or output, the Wizard reports success, and there appears to be a signed apk.

However when trying to upload the apk to the Android Market it reports that the APK does not contain an AndroidManifest.xml. I confirmed that the signed APK indeed is missing the AndroidManifest.xml file for some reason.

Environment:
Windows 7
Elipse Indigo
ADT 15.0.0.v201110251216-213216

Assuming something is wrong with my dev environment. Just at a loss to figure out what it might be. Odd that the debug APK gets generated properly and includes the AndroidManifest.xml but when attempting to Export the APK either signed or unsigned via the Wizard does not include this necessary file int the resultant APK and the tool is still reporting success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the .apk file using winzip and manually add AndroidManifest.xml
I'm not sure if it'll work - but it's so easy that its worth a shot!

Comment: Yeah, that might work assuming the manifest file is the only thing missing. But I was able to work around the problem by using a different machine. I'm more interested in getting an answer or problem shooting steps that will fix the existing environment so I can publish apps to the marketplace from it. As it is the wizard reports success and there are no warnings or errors.

Comment: Did you try creating a new project ?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a problem that same. But I didn't resolve this

I'm guessing that eclipse have problems. And I build source at another pc, no problem happen.